# Android Place Picker : Restrict user to select place only in specific area

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-places-api

I'm using Google Place picker to let the user pick a place of his choice.
My question is how can i restrict user to select a place only in Pakistan? I am using Google place picker following :

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Ewmjc/Country_bounds ???

Answer (score 3):

Well I used this for my Place picker

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                        .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
                        .setCountry("IN")
                        .build();
```

For Pakistan use PK for Alpha2 code and PAK for Alpha3 Code, in this case alpha2 code will apply

You have to pass your filter and it will bound your requests to a country.

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                    .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                                    .build(this);
```